# how to redirect to a specefic route when validator failed in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to register user from index page but When validator failed then want to redirect to register page.

I am tired to solve this problem . can't customize Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php page.

Here is the code

```
protected function getRedirectUrl() {
  return route('register');
}
protected function validator(array $data) {
  $this->getRedirectUrl();
  return Validator::make($data, [ 'name' => 'required|max:255', 'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users', 'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed', ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the below method which generate the previous url in your controller and override the default one add following methods in your controller

in your controller where you have defined `$this->validate` call define below method and use Request

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // add at the top

protected function getRedirectUrl() {
  return route('register');
}

protected function validator(array $data) {
  return $this->validate(request(), [ 'name' => 'required|max:255', 'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users', 'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed', ]);
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all());

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: where did you place this method can you show that controller code?

Comment: protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
   return route('register');  
}

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        
        $this->getRedirectUrl();
        
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

Comment: i have added it in registerController

Comment: what about surrounding the `$this->validate(..)` with `try{$this->validate($request, $rule)}catch(ValidationException e)` block? source of idea, from [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php#L55) that calls [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php#L89). sorry, my bad, i thought you're using `ValidatesRequests` trait.

Comment: i think need to customize  following line/ function :https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php#L130

Comment: if you are using $this->validate than defining getRedirectUrl() should work
because $this->validate() uses validation trait and the above method is defined inside validation trait and used to determine the previous url

Comment: no need to modify the framework code, its simple trait which adds method to your class and you can override that and that is what i have suggest instead of using Validator::make use $this->validate()

Comment: i am updating answer

Comment: if its correct and working mark answer as correct so other can take help.. :)